# Seeing all the crafting materials on a recipe in Diablo 3 on console?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

I just found the plan for Staff of Herding in Diablo 3 Reaper of Souls on Xbox One, and checking the recipe shows me 3 materials needed:

- Wirt's Bell
- Black Mushroom
- Gibbering Gemstone

I found the names of those items from finding the recipe online.

So, here's my two questions related to the crafting window:

- Apparenly the recipe requires more than those 3 materials, it also requires Liquid Rainbow and Leoric's Shinbone. **How can I see those materials in the crafting window?** Meaning, how would I know that the recipe requires more than the 3 shown materials if I didn't go looking for the recipe online? The window only shows the 3 first(?) materials.
- **Can I see the names of the materials in the crafting window somewhere?** Assume that I don't have the item so I can't go looking for the item by appearance in my stash, how would I know what to search for? A lot of item databases only has the names of the materials, not their icons, which does not tell me which materials I have and which ones I miss, other than hunting through my stash for all the icons.

Again, note that my question is about the console version of Diablo 3, in particular (for me) the Xbox One version.

Comment: What about the liquid rainbow? I have been trying for days to get it. Is that one of the items you don't need for the Xbox one? A lot of what I found online talks about the Xbox 360.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [diablo forum post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/9882708462), it does actually require less materials on the console version.

And [this one](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/9873847391#1) seems to confirm this too for Xbox precisely, [this one for ps4](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/14058736818#1) even if I doubt the console version are different from one console to another.

Comment: Oh, nice, then I'm only missing one item then, not 2 as I previously thought. However, I have already found Leoric's Shinbone, one of the materials that wasn't shown and is apparently now not needed. Wonder what use I have for that item then, but that's another question.